# iphone/ipad memory leak from NSString assigned to itself

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks

I have two leaks shown by the instruments tool. I have looked around on google but I haven't seen exactly my problem on there.

Problem #1:

```
self.wallText = [[text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

I have tried various configurations of the above line but all leak. I need to do both those trimming operations. 'text' is declared with either @"" or stringWithFormat.

My other issue is with the following line:

```
    NSString * value = [elements objectAtIndex:i+1];
if ([value length] >= 2 && [[value substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"S_"]){
   value = [value substringFromIndex:2]; // LEAK HERE
    }
```

I need to get all of the string except for the first 2 characters so I don't know how I could release it first or something... if that is indeed what I should be doing.

I could get away wtih leaks before with previous projects but this one is very memory intensive and I need all the memory I can get!

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: in order for people to answer effectively you need add some more info: (a) how is value declared and initialized. (b) how is the @property defined for walltext.

Comment: Yes wall post is defined with retain. So does that mean 'text' won't leak?

Comment: Don't use `retain` with `NSString` properties. Use `copy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you declare `@property (retain)` for wallText, did you do `[wallText release]` in dealloc method?

Double check above things and you will not have leaks any more

**For Updated Part:**

It is really strange that you have a memory leak there. Because at first, your `value` points to an `autoreleased` object then it points to another `autoreleased` object which I think is fine.

Comment: +1 To provide a bit of detail: this works because the `@synthesize`'d setter method with the "retain" semantic releases the current value before setting and retaining the new one. So it's memory-safe to "overwrite" those sorts of properties directly.

Comment: No I wasn't using release in the dealloc method. So is that always the case... Whenever I retain a property on the @property declaration I have to release it in dealloc? Is that the case even for IBoutlet properties?

Comment: yeah, if you declare a @property(retain) you have to release in dealloc even for IBOutlet. It is not just `@property(retain)` but also if you own some instance variable (by `alloc, retain and copy`) you have to release in dealloc. Also make sure that you didn't overrelease it as well (by always using self.variable for property)

Comment: Ok cool good to know thanks for that. I am still getting a leak for my issue # 2. I have updated the code sample.

Comment: You should create another question that will attract more answers:). People usually not look at the old, updated question

Answer (score 0):

have u use alloc for value. `value = [value substringFromIndex:2];`   .here now value is referencing to new autorelease string. so u can not release previous object.

Comment: I never use alloc to create a new string. It's always using the literal, assigning from another variable, or using one of the string utility methods.